# i got this problem while creating migration

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, svg-animationelements

I'm running 'php artisan migrate' I got this error:

> ([Illuminate\Database\QueryException] SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or
>   access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is
>   767 bytes (SQL: alter table users add unique
>   users_email_unique(email))) after that In the AppServiceProvider.php

add this code

> (use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;and
>   Schema::defaultStringLength(191);)

now I get another error

> (PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use Illuminate\Support\Facades`enter code
>   here`\Schema as Schema because the name is already in use in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php on line
>   7)

the following are the AppServiceProvider.php code

```
<?php


namespace App\Providers;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use mysql_xdevapi\Schema;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider

{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
           Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()`enter code here`
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine you're getting this error because you've tried to import 2 `Schema` classes.

Try removing `use mysql_xdevapi\Schema;` from the top of your `AppServiceProvider`.

Comment: i remove the use mysql_xdevapi\Schema; now i got a new error

Comment: the problem is (  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
   (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = laravel and table_name = migrations)


In Connector.php line 68:

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
)

Comment: i dont know but that time my php artisan migrate give this problim. but its solve after delete my data base tables